# Trying to figure out how to get current face of a cube

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, css

I've been playing around with [Paul Hayes' 3d Cube](http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/) trying to figure out an algorithm that can determine the face of the cube that's currently facing the user at any given time.  Here is the relevant CSS of the faces:

```
#cube .one  {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

#cube .two {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
}

#cube .three {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

#cube .four {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}

#cube .five {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

#cube .six {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I've collected some sample data (purely from entering arbitrary x and y angle values and seeing how the browser handles it) that I thought might make it easier to see a pattern from which an algorithm can be extrapolated from, but so far I'm not seeing anything. Pasting below as it may help someone else.

```
Face    Angle (xAngle, yAngle)
--------------------------------
1      (-90, 0) (-90, -90)
2      (0, 0) (180, 180)
3      (0, -90) (180, 90) (-180, 90)
4      (0, 180) (180, 0) (-180, 0) (0, -180)
5      (0, 90)
6      (90, 0) (90, 90) (90, 180)
```

Answer (score 1):

When You rotate cube, some style is added to `id="cube"`

```
<div id="cube" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);">
```

If `rotateX = ((270 + n*360)deg)` face **`one`** will be facing the user.
Similar with others. I dont know jQuery or JS that well, so this is just pure math.

Comment: could you explain what n represents? Maybe give an example? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this as a start:

```
// cube and the pattern to extract the rotation values
var cube = document.getElementById('cube');
var pattern = /rotateX\(([-?\w\d]+)\)\s?rotateY\(([-?\w\d]+)\)/g;

// extract each value
result = pattern.exec(cube.style.transform); // rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-360deg)

// if we found a result
if(result){

    var x = parseInt(result[1]); // 0deg
    var y = parseInt(result[2]); // -360deg

    // the side we're looking for -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3
    var side = (y/90) % 4;

    console.log(side)    
}
else{
    // the property hasn't been set on the cube so we must be on the first one
    console.log(0);
}
```

This works on firefox, I'm not sure if the `transform` style property is consistent across browsers. Also since it's only a start it won't find the top and bottom sides yet.